# Shadertoy. How to cycle the effect?

Tags: glsl, webgl

I'm trying to create a shader that cyclically turns an image to black and white and then again to colorful. And I have written a code that turns the image to B&W:

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{    
    vec2 xy = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    vec4 texColor = texture(iChannel0, xy);
    fragColor = (texColor + texColor.yzxw + texColor.zxyw) / 3.;
    //fragColor = texColor; This is for turning back to colorful
}
```

So the problem is that I do not understand how to cycle this process. I think I should consider using ITime, but I'm not sure about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `mix` and `sin` functions to cycle between 2 states in your shader. Something like this should work:

```c
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{    
    vec2 xy = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    vec4 texColor = texture(iChannel0, xy);
    vec4 grey = (texColor + texColor.yzxw + texColor.zxyw) / 3.;
    float t = sin(iTime*5.)*.5+.5; // make it cyclic
    // mix between the colorful and greyscale version
    fragColor = mix(grey, texColor, t);
}
```